# Images in table view displayed in simulator but not displayed in my iPod device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4

I have a table view, and I have image file in my application folder and in Xcode.proj

Basically table view cell has an image view in it.

When I write code like this

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"] ;
cell.textlabel.text = @"icon Image"
```

it shows image and text in simulator, but only text in device.

What is the problem?

Comment: have you added image in your app bundle, copied that there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two Reasons -

1. Image is not present in your application bundle, add image in your project folder.
   (It is available on simulator, as you are referencing this from some location of your mac.)
2. name is not correct(simulator is not case sensitive, while device is).

Comment: icon image already in my project folder and is displayed as icon in both simulator and device also.. how s'd i add it in main bundle

Comment: have you verified the name of image - "Icon.png" or "icon.png"?

Answer (score 2):

Simulator is not case sensitive while device is. It should
 be lowercase

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]; 
cell.textlabel.text = @"icon Image";
```

Also are you sure that the icon is in the main bundle/ application folder...
Just add it to your project...

Comment: icon image already in my project folder and is displayed as icon in both simulator and device also.. how s'd i add it in main bundle

Comment: basically you just drag it to the project... youve already dont that tghough... fixed the lowercase

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible problems:

1. one is you may forgot to add it to bundle of your project
2. the other is simulator is case insensitive while device is sensitive, you should make sure that your extension of image is same as in your code like if there is icone.PNG, the write @"icon.PNG" not @"icon.png".